List generation of ggplot2 scale_y_continuous()
I am trying to generate a named list of ggplot2 y-scales for usage with facet plot in combination with `
facetted_pos_scales(x = NULL, y = NULL)` from the ggh4x package.
The ultimate goal is to scale the facets' secondary y-axes independently of each other. The limits for secondary y-scales are saved in a data frame.
I fail to (1) create a named list for each row [more precisely, I cannot evaluate the column Name to its respective value, e.g. "A"] and (2) force the evaluation of the arguments to the transformation function at the time of the list creation [e.g. min_to -> 0 etc.].
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df = tibble(Name = c('A','B'), 
       min_from = c(0,0), 
       max_from = c(1,1), 
       min_to = c(100,100), 
       max_to = c(1000,1000))
df |> 
  group_by(Name) |> 
  mutate(y_scale = list(Name = scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(transform = \(x) rescale(x, 
                                              to = c(min_to, max_to), 
                                              from = c(min_from, max_from)))
    )))


Not sure whether is necessary to have the scales stored inside a list column. Personally I would simply use a list, e.g. you could use split and lapply to create a list of scales which you could then pass to ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales:
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggh4x)

scale_y <- df |>
  split(~Name) |>
  lapply(\(sc) {
    scale_y_continuous(
      sec.axis = sec_axis(transform = \(x) rescale(x,
        to = c(sc$min_to, sc$max_to),
        from = c(sc$min_from, sc$max_from)
      ))
    )
  })

scale_y
#> $A
#> <ScaleContinuousPosition>
#>  Range:  
#>  Limits:    0 --    1
#> 
#> $B
#> <ScaleContinuousPosition>
#>  Range:  
#>  Limits:    0 --    1

data.frame(
  x = 1:10, y = 1:10, Name = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10)
) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Name, scales = "free_y") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(y = scale_y)



Thank you, @stefan, for your help. While this answer does not address the original problems, it provides a straightforward solution to attain the ultimate goal.
